# How to sum values of two dataframes with different shapes when one is multilevel index and the other one is not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes: `eta1.shape = (8004, 29), eta2.shape = (138,)`

```
eta1= 
        id/uniqueID      var0    var1    var2    var3    var4 ...  var28
        5171/0            10.0    2.8     0.0     5.0     1.0  ...  9.4  
        5171/1            40.9    2.5     3.4     4.5     1.3  ...  7.7  
        5171/2            60.7    3.1     5.2     6.6     3.4  ...  1.0
        ...
        5171/57           0.5     1.3     5.1     0.5     0.2  ...  0.4
        4567/0            1.5     2.0     1.0     4.5     0.1  ...  0.4  
        4567/1            4.4     2.0     1.3     6.4     0.1  ...  3.3  
        4567/2            6.3     3.0     1.5     7.6     1.6  ...  1.6
        ...
        4567/57           0.7     1.4     1.4     0.3     4.2  ...  1.7
       ... 
        9584/0            0.3     2.6     0.0     5.2     1.6  ...  9.7  
        9584/1            0.5     1.2     8.3     3.4     1.3  ...  1.7  
        9584/2            0.7     3.0     5.6     6.6     3.0  ...  1.0
        ...
        9584/57           0.7     1.3     0.1     0.0     2.0  ...  1.7

eta2= 
        id     var28
        5171    67.0
        4567    98.9
        9584    47.7
        ...
        8707    56.3
```

In `eta2`, I have one value per each `id`. I need to add the value for each `id` in `eta2` to all the columns of `eta1` with the same `id`, like `eta = eta1+eta2`. So for example the results for `id=5171` should be as follow:

```
eta.loc[5171] = 
            id/uniqueID       var0         var1         ...  var28
            5171/0            10.0+67.0    2.8+67.0     ...  9.4+67.0  
            5171/1            40.9+67.0    2.5+67.0     ...  7.7+67.0  
            5171/2            60.7+67.0    3.1+67.0     ...  1.0+67.0
            ...
            5171/57           0.5+67.0     1.3+67.0     ...  0.4+67.0
```

Doing the sum by `eta = eta1.add(eta2)` gives wrong results because they don't have the same levels. I can't remove the levels, I need them for later calculations. So instead I tried to add a new level to `eta2` and then do the sum, but I'm getting this error:

```
eta2['uniq_id'] = eta2.groupby('id').cumcount()
eta2 = eta2.set_index(['uniq_id'], append=True)
eta = eta1.add(eta2, level=0)
error: typeError: Join one level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous
```

How can I do this sum?

Comment: How working if use `eta = eta1.add(eta2)` ?

Comment: yes! I'll update the question to be more clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with `Series` with `eta2['var28']` and `axis=0` `level=0` parameter:

```
eta = eta1.add(eta2['var28'], axis=0, level=0)
print (eta)
                var0   var1   var2   var3   var4  var28
id   uniqueID                                          
5171 0          77.0   69.8   67.0   72.0   68.0   76.4
     1         107.9   69.5   70.4   71.5   68.3   74.7
     2         127.7   70.1   72.2   73.6   70.4   68.0
     57         67.5   68.3   72.1   67.5   67.2   67.4
4567 0         100.4  100.9   99.9  103.4   99.0   99.3
     1         103.3  100.9  100.2  105.3   99.0  102.2
     2         105.2  101.9  100.4  106.5  100.5  100.5
     57         99.6  100.3  100.3   99.2  103.1  100.6
9584 0          48.0   50.3   47.7   52.9   49.3   57.4
     1          48.2   48.9   56.0   51.1   49.0   49.4
     2          48.4   50.7   53.3   54.3   50.7   48.7
     57         48.4   49.0   47.8   47.7   49.7   49.4
```

If added cumulative count `MultiIndex`:

```
eta2['uniq_id'] = eta2.groupby('id').cumcount()
eta2 = eta2.set_index(['uniq_id'], append=True)

eta = eta1.add(eta2['var28'], axis=0)
print (eta)
                        var0   var1  var2   var3  var4  var28
id   uniqueID uniq_id                                        
4567 0        0        100.4  100.9  99.9  103.4  99.0   99.3
     1        0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
     2        0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
     57       0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
5171 0        0         77.0   69.8  67.0   72.0  68.0   76.4
     1        0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
     2        0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
     57       0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
8707 NaN      0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
9584 0        0         48.0   50.3  47.7   52.9  49.3   57.4
     1        0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
     2        0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
     57       0          NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
```